# python tensorflow using dropout on input layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning

I am using python with tf and looking for the proper way to mask some of the input while training an auto de-noising encoder for mnist data.

I tried using dropout for the input layer, same way as i am using it for the hidden layers, the results are not great, it's hard to know what is the issue with the auto encoder, as it is hard to debug all deep learning architectures

The code that i used for the dropout, including on the input layer:

```
def encoder_2(x):
    global dims #list of dimensions including the input
    layers = [x]
    dropouts = []
    for i,dim in list(enumerate(dims))[:-1]:
        dropouts.append(tf.nn.dropout(layers[-1], keep_prob=keep_prob))
        try:
            layers.append(tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(dropouts[-1], weights["encoder_h%d"%(i+1)]), biases["encoder_b%d"%(i+1)])))
        except:
            pass

    return layers[-1]
```

I found [here](https://gist.github.com/blackecho/3a6e4d512d3aa8aa6cf9) some implementation for input masking, but I find it hard to believe that there is no built in function in tf for that.

Is the proper way to mask the input is dropout? if not, is there a built in way to use masking (dropout) on the input?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the keep probability is different for the input layer. First, try to keep all the input `keep_prob=1.0` and see if you get similar result to no dropout. If you try `keep_prob=0.0`, you should get only noise (no input). This is how you can debug this kind of system. When you are sure the limits work, try something like `keep_prob=0.8` which is usually good for mnist.

Comment: Thanks! can you recommend any good working mnist auto encoder example with accuracy > 97% ?